# how to sizeof the whole struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I have the following struct defined:

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
} A;

typedef struct
{
   int b;
} B;

typedef struct
{
   A a,
   B b[10];
} C;
```

while the `sizeof(C)` will be `sizeof(A) + sizeof(B) * 10`? I want to have the whole size of the struct C, how to get it?

Comment: sizeof(C) - what have you tried, and how is it failing?

Comment: I do not know how this sizeof will perform to the struct like that

Comment: @user2131316: `sizeof` is just programmed to do it the right way. You can rely on it.

Comment: sizeof(C) is "whole size of the struct C".  That's it!

Comment: what I mean is: is sizeof(C) will be sizeof(A) + sizeof(B)?

Comment: no `sizeof(c)` with be `sizeof(a) + 10*sizeof(b)` plus any padding.

Comment: @user2131316 +1 && do need this stuff for homework? application of an array (for int) would be possible instead of your construct (concerning struct B).

Comment: The size of C *is* (at least) the size of A and the size of 10 lots of B -- you've got ten of them in there. Why would it be the size of A plus the size of a single B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(C)` will be at least `sizeof(A) + sizeof(B) * 10`

Aggregate types may be bigger due to alignment issues.  Probably not in this case, given we're really talking about 11 ints.

Comment: May it be less for other aggregated types? So can part of the second member be put into the trailing padding of the first?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It's easy to see this isn't allowed for types which you're allowed to copy/restore with `memcpy` (since restoring a value of the first member would clobber the value of the second). It's less obvious whether the standard forbids it for non-trivial types, I don't know the answer off-hand but I suspect it is forbidden.

Comment: I mean in C. It is allowed in C++ definitely for nontrivial classes (and gcc does it).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, just use sizeof on an instance of C:

```
C c;
sizeof(c);
```

Comment: @interjay Yes, thanks - I was making assumptions of OP's needs.